# find all vectors b that are in $span \{\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Here's what I am trying to figure out: Find all vectors $\vec{b}$ that are in $span \{\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$ where $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are vectors.

I'm given specific vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$, but I really just want to ask about concepts. I can do the algebra, certainly.

I understand what it means for something to be in the Span of a set of vectors (it is a linear combination of the vectors). And I suspect that I know what it means to find all vectors $\vec{b}$ that are in $span \{\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$, where $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are vectors. I believe that, given vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$, I need to set those vectors with some arbitrary vector $\vec{b}$ as the augmented column, with entries $b_1,b_2,b_3$, to form the augmented matrix. Then I need to reduce the augmented matrix to reduced echelon form, and, if necessary, find the values of $b_1,b_2,b_3$ that would make the system inconsistent (i.e. a nonsense row with zeroes in the coefficient columns of a row and a non-zero number in the augmented column of the same row). Then I would define $\vec{b}$ in terms of what I have in that column after row reduction, barring those values of $b_1,b_2$ and $b_3$ that would make a nonsense row.

Does this seem sensible to you?

Comment: The sentence "find all vectors in the span of these three vectors" really means "describe all vectors in the span," and that, in turn, really means "describe the span in some other way besides saying it is the span of these vectors." You can do *that* in several ways. One is to do row reduction to find out which vectors are independent, and then throw out the dependent vectors. Then you can describe the span as the subspace generated by the basis you get after throwing out the dependent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$ are linearly independent, then all vectors in $\text{span}(\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w})$ are simply all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

As you say

> it is a linear combination of the vectors

so all vectors in $\text{span}(\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w})$ are $\alpha_1 \vec{u} + \alpha_2 \vec{v} + \alpha_3 \vec{w}$ with $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, oh, okay. When I row reduce, there is not a pivot in each column (i.e. the columns are not linearly independent). So what to do in this case? As I described?

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at an example.

Suppose $u = (1, 2, 3)$ and $v = (3, 2, 1)$.
Еvery vector $b$ in the span of $u$,$v$ is of the form $b = \alpha u + \beta v$. So

$b = \alpha(1, 2, 3) + \beta(3, 2, 1) = (\alpha + 3\beta, 2\alpha + 2\beta, 3\alpha + \beta)$.

Therefore $\{(\alpha + 3\beta, 2\alpha + 2\beta, 3\alpha + \beta) | \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is the required span of $u$,$v$.